# Hashtable и свои объекты в качестве ключа

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Просветите пожалуйста по такому вопросу. Решил я для эксперимента использовать свой класс в качестве ключа в коллекции `HasTable`, и соответственно зная, что данная коллекция сортирует элементы по хеш-коду ключа и при добавлении в коллекцию анализирует нет ли уже ключа с таким же хешкодом, создал свой класс. В своем классе я переопределил метод `GetHashCode`, причем переопределил таким образом, что он возвращает случайное число. Однако при этом код работает как я и ожидаю. Вот код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add(new b(1),"ds");
        ht.Add(new b(2),"dsa");
        Console.WriteLine(ht[new b(1)]);
    }
}
class b
{
    public int x;
    public b(int y)
    {
        x = y;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new Random().Next();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((b)obj).x == this.x;
    }
}
```

Но "мистика" начинается дальше, я было подумал, что раз он таким образом работает(то есть находит по ключу строку), то вообще в своем классе можно не переопределять метод `GetHashCode`, если при совершенно случайных числах, выдается правильный результат. Я благополучно закоментировал переопределение этого метода, но тогда все перестало работать, то есть перестал находить элементы по ключу. И тут возник вопрос, зачем ему вообще нужен метод `GetHashCode` для поиска по ключу, если в `Equals` весь алгоритм сравнения описан ? Перед всеми этими манипуляциями, е решил , что эта коллекция вообще не использует `Equals` моего класса для сравнения у себя элементов, однако, оказалось, что если не переопределять `Equals` то поиск по ключу тоже не происходит. Почему так ?
Еще неразбериха в том, почему если при указанной выше реализации GetHashCode добавить два элемента таким образом

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add(new b(1),"ds");
        ht.Add(new b(1),"dsa");
        Console.WriteLine(ht[new b(1)]);
```

то будет исключение, что уже данный объект был добавлен. Ведь хешкоды у них разные ??

Получается очень интересная ситуация, если в этом коде

```
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add(new b(1), "ds");
        ht.Add(new b(2), "dsa");
        Console.WriteLine(ht[new b(1)]);
    }
}
class b
{
    public int x;
    public b(int y)
    {
        x = y;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return new Random().Next();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((b)obj).x == this.x;
    }
}
```

заменить `ht.Add(new b(2), "dsa");` на `ht.Add(new b(1), "dsa");` то выходит эксепшн о том, что такой элемент уже есть (хотя если не изменять то все ок). Это при том что генерируются разные числа которые вообще никак не зависят от аргумента. Однако если после изменения расскоментировать `//System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` тогда все работает логично

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что семя для объекта класса `Random` зависит от текущего времени и не успевает смениться между двумя вызывами `GetHashCode()`, из-за чего `new Random().Next()` возвращает одинаковые значения: попробуйте поставить стоп-точки или сменить генератор на статический счётчик, и словить исключение уже не получится.

Comment: Ниче себе, в жизни бы не догадался. Я думал, что рандом использует помимо времени еще какие-то внешние факторы. Оказалось и правда. Если добавить Thread.Sleep(1000) то тогда все норм.

Comment: @polyakov_s, занятный баг. Сейчас сам пытаюсь припомнить, где мог в проектах также написать.

Answer (score 9):

Возврат разных значений при каждом вызове `GetHashCode` — худшее, что только возможно представить. Так делать нельзя. Если вы написали тест, в котором система ведёт себя «как ожидается», это не очень хороший тест. В реальном коде ожидайте проблем.

Наверняка со сменой хэшкода вы просто не сможете найти элемент в `HashTable`.

Если вы сделали что-то, что запрещено документацией, и оно работает здесь и сейчас, не стоит ожидать, что оно будет работать и в будущем. Если ваш код перестанет работать по каким-то причинам, виноваты будете вы и только вы.

Поэтому лучше всегда играть по правилам.

---

По поводу того, что происходит.

Хэш-таблица устроена следующим образом. Все данные разделены на несколько «ящиков» (buckets). Ящик выбирается в зависимости от хэшкода. При добавлении элемента, сначала вычисляется хэшкод, находится нужный ящик, и дальнейшие операции ограничиваются этим ящиком. Затем, элементы из ящика сравниваются с данным элементом при помощи `Equals(object)`, и если они все не равны, то элемент не найден и происходит добавление.¹

То же самое происходит и при удалении.

Это означает, что если вы пытаетесь удалить объект, то он будет искаться только в «ящике», соответствующем его хэшкоду. Если вдруг хэшкод объекта меняется, никто не переложит его автоматически в другой ящик. Поэтому при смене хэшкода алгоритм поиска будет искать его в неверном ящике, не найдёт, и не сможет удалить.

Обратите внимание, что `Hashtable` — устаревший класс, пользоваться им не надо. Нужно использовать [`Dictionary<K, V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). В этом случае у вас кроме `Equals(object)` используется и интерфейс `IEquatable<K>`, так что если вас заботит производительность, имеет смысл его имплементировать.

---

¹ Отсюда жёсткое требование о том, что равные (по `Equals`) объекты **обязаны** иметь одинаковый хэшкод.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы добиться уникальности генератора:

```
var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Для вашего примера работает.

Вместо `HashTable` лучше использовать типобезопасную релизацию `Dictionary<T,K>`.

Comment: Иногда значения DateTime.Now.Millisecond совпадают и исключение выдаётся, а иногда нет. Вы изобрели русскую рулетку, поздравляю

Comment: Ой, пардон. Накосячил :) Ticks там

Comment: Тогда уж `Ticks.GetHashCode()` или `(int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks % int.MaxValue)` ибо тип не подходит

Comment: @pavelip конструктор Random без параметров как раз использует  `Environment.TickCount` : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,5d22f8880fc9f8d9. Так что эффект будет такой же - иногда работает, иногда - нет.

Comment: На Windows 7 DateTime.Ticks точнее почти в 15 раз чем Environment.TickCount.

Comment: @pavelip "почти" - это не решение. Random лучше создавать статический, а не каждый раз новый.

Comment: Ну, каждый новый раз - это понятно. У автора так было, я не предлагал создавать новый объект. Но статический `Random` проблему с одинаковыми случайными числами не решит.

Comment: @pavelip почему статический рандом не решит проблему? вопрос же на самом деле о том, почему два подряд созданных рандома почти всегда выдают одинаковое значение. статический рандом эту проблему решает - два одинаковых значения подряд будут выпадать не чаще, чем этого можно ожидать от рандома (т.е. очень-очень редко).

Comment: и кстати, без @pashapash нотификации о комментах приходят только автору ответа - т.е. вам.

Comment: @PashaPash если вы про статический объект в каждом классе, то он не решит?!

Comment: @pavelip не понял последнее утверждение. один статический объект решит. два и более (==в каждом классе) - не решат.